# Get all record from table till last updation in table

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I want all records from table till I updated last time that table I am trying update_time of information_schema.tables but unable to understand how to use. Is there any way to do it Please suggest me. 
**Note : I don't have createdate column in my table that's why I am trying from information_schema update_time**
For Example : I have a table tblstock and I want to fetch stock for condition (where date <= "searching date for stock" ) but i don't have createdate column that update after every entry in table that's why I am facing problem to get all record from that table for this condition.

Comment: Add some more information in question ! its unclear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not a column to store the update time, you can't get what you want in this case.

Even you get the UPDATE_TIME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, you still can't know update/insert datetime for each rows in table.

You need to store the update_time in your own table.

Answer (score 0):

Get the last update time of your table through `information_schema`

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'tabname'
```

Comment: I have already used it for getting last update time of specific table but how to use it to fetch record from my table